# Which MySQL field(s) should I use to properly store date time with millisecond precision?

Tags: mysql, datetime, precision, timestamp

I know MySQL only has a second precision when storing datetimes and timestamps. So what is the best, simplest and most robust workaround you would recommend to include milliseconds?

So far I have seen DECIMAL(17,3) combined with SQL functions, and others serializing the datetime on a VARCHAR. Another idea would be to store the millisecond component in another column.

Comment: Isn't there an UDF for that? Yep: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/10/30/how-i-built-the-now_usec-udf-for-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

> "...microseconds cannot be stored into a column of any temporal data
>   type. Any microseconds part is discarded.
>
> As of MySQL 5.0.8, conversion of TIME or DATETIME values to numeric
>   form (for example, by adding +0) results in a double value with a
>   microseconds part of .000000:"

So, it looks like using a doubel is the way to go.

Comment: That will involve rounding error though, isn't there a bigint clone, like decimal(20,10)?